# Error in using find() function in map<string, int>

Tags: c++, c++11, hash, stl, unordered-map

Below is the corrected my code. **The error has been solved.**

```
unordered_map<string, int> map;
int m = B.size();
int n=A.size();
for(int i=0; i<m; i++) map[B[i]]++;
for(int end=0; end<n; end=end+1)
{

  if(map.find(A.substr(end, 3))!=map.end() && map[A.substr(end, 3)]>0)
  {     
             something here;
  }

}
```

I find error while using the find() operator or " != " for a map with key as string and value as int.

```
*solution.cpp: In member function 'std::vector<int> Solution::findSubstring(std::string, const std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&)':
solution.cpp:16:36: error: no match for 'operator!=' (operand types are 'std::unordered_map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>::iterator' {aka 'std::__detail::_Node_iterator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>, false, true>'} and 'bool')
   20 |       if(map.find(A.substr(end, 3))!=A.empty() && map[A.substr(end, 3)]>0)
      |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
      |                  |                          |
      |                  |                          bool
      |                  std::unordered_map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>::iterator {aka std::__detail::_Node_iterator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>, false, true>}
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9.2.0/iosfwd:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9.2.0/ios:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9.2.0/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9.2.0/iostream:39,
                 from solution.h:7,
                 from solution.cpp:-3:
/usr/include/c++/9.2.0/bits/postypes.h:227:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _StateT> bool std::operator!=(const std::fpos<_StateT>&, const std::fpos<_StateT>&)'
  227 |     operator!=(const fpos<_StateT>& __lhs, const fpos<_StateT>& __rhs)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
```

Comment: `map.find(A.substr(end, 3))!=A.empty()` -> `map.find(A.substr(end, 3))!=map.end()`

Comment: what do you expect `map.find(...) != A.empty()` to do? Don't use `using namespace std;` in combination with variables named `map`

Comment: please include the error message as text in the question

Comment: the error message tells you that you try to compare an iterator with a `bool` that just doesnt make sense....

Comment: I assume that `empty()` instead of `end()` is a typo (as mentioned in comment above). Voting to close.

Comment: `map.find` returns an **iterator**. If you found something then that iterator will point to the found item, if you didn't find anything then that iterator will point to map.end(). So the correct code is `map.find(A.substr(end, 3)) != map.end()`. You can't program the STL without understanding iterators.

Comment: The error has been solved, it was a typo thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `find` will return the iterator which fullfill the condition or the end iterator. So you may use map.end() instead of A.empty()